# async_read_until handler called twice

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am trying to use boost asio library to implement network programming.
Here is the code which is called when some data(which ends with "##") arrives at the endpoint.

```
{
    boost::asio::async_read_until(m_socket, m_response,
                std::string("##"),
                boost::bind(&CTcpClient::HandleReceive,
                                shared_from_this(),
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

}


void CTcpClient::HandleReceive(const ErrorCodeType p_errorCode, size_t p_length)
{
    IN_FUNCTION

    if ( !p_errorCode )
    {
        logInfo(STR("Data received ..."));

        boost::asio::async_read_until(m_socket, m_response,
            std::string("##"),
            boost::bind(&CTcpClient::HandleReceive,
                            shared_from_this(),
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        m_onReceiveSignal(sbuf2s(m_response));

    }
    else
    {
        Shutdown(p_errorCode);
    }

    OUT_FUNCTION
}
```

Let's say, the data that is sent to the end point is "KINGS##". Hence, the Handlereceive should be called once. But in my code, this is being called twice, once with "KINGS##" and another with a null string.

Can somebody tell me what is the reason and how to fix it ?

Comment: What is the type of `m_response`?

Comment: m_response is of boost::asio::streambuf type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be clearing out your `m_response` buffer, up to the token, after a successful read.

Because you aren't doing this before re-issuing an async read, your response buffer still has the `##` characters in it, so the read is going to complete immediately.

As a side note, the `async_read_until` call *may* read data beyond the ##, so you have to be careful to only clear up to and including the ##, but not past it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to call async_read_until(...) after m_onReceiveSignal(...). 
Change the order of both inside Handlereceive.

That is under the assumption the first time you call the Handlereceive is from another method (connect maybe) through async_read_untill(...)